# looping through rows and adding values

Tags: excel, for-loop, sum, vba

Here is my code

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
  For x = 5 To x = 30 Step 1
    Set addRange1 = .Range(.Cells(x, 4), .Cells(x, myCount2))
    cell(x, myCount2 + 2).Value = Application.Sum(addRange1)
Next
End With
```

First row would be cell(5,4) to cell(5, 20) or something. Sum the values of that row and display it in cell (5,22)
Repeat up to x = 30

Hope that is clear
Getting blank cells where sum value should be

Comment: You should be getting `Sub or Function not defined` on `Cell`.  Use `Cells`, also do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module as you've not declared your variables.

Comment: i have declared addRange1 and myCount2, just didnt include it in the post

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook this code snippet is within sub btw

Answer (score 0):

This would be correct:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 5 To 30
        Set addRange1 = .Range(.Cells(x, 4), .Cells(x, myCount2))
        Cells(x, myCount2 + 2).Value = Application.Sum(addRange1)
    Next
End With
```

The `For ... Next` was incorrect. Instead of `To x = 30` it has to be `To 30`.

> Info what happened here: If you walked through your code step-by-step you would have noticed that everything inside your `For ... Next` is never executed. This is because x = 30 in the `For` sets `x` to the value `30` and this is the end of the `For` so the `For` gets never executed.

The `Step 1` isn't necessary, it is `1` by default you may remove it or keep it but it is not necessary.

And as Darren Bartrup-Cook mentioned it has to be `Cells` instead of `Cell`.